# Relationship between area of similar polygons and their corresponding lengths

Tags: geometry

It is known that ratio of the areas of two similar polygons is equal to the square of the ratio of the corresponding sides. Could one advise me how to prove this assertion? Do we divide the polygon into triangles? Thank you.

Comment: You might get some ideas by considering the "Shoelace formula" for polygon areas.  (example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula#Proof_for_a_quadrilateral_and_general_polygon).  I hope this helps.

Comment: yes. Result follows when all the divided triangles are added together.

Comment: @Mick Actually you can prove this without resorting to cutting up into triangles...

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Yes. I have seen your work using transformations.

Comment: @Mick: Thank you. Could you elaborate on using the shoelace formula?

Comment: Will do that in a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to use the reasoning from a quadrilateral ABCD with AC dividing it into two triangles, namely $a = [\triangle BAC]$ and $b = [\triangle BDC]$.

The similar target will be similarly named as $a’ = [\triangle B’A’C’]$ and $b’ = [\triangle B’D’C’]$

We assume the area and side relation is true for two similar triangles. [For simplicity, I use the side AC. Actually any pair of corresponding sides also works because the image is just k times the original by lengths.]

$a’ = (\dfrac {A’C’}{AC})^2 \times a$

$b’ = (\dfrac {A’C’}{AC})^2 \times b$

$a’ + b’ = (\dfrac {A’C’}{AC})^2 \times (a + b)$

[area of the image] =  $(\dfrac {A’C’}{AC})^2 \times$ [area of the original]

Comment: Thank you, it seems we do not need to use the shoelace formula? Knowledge of area of triangle $=$ Base $\times$ perpendicular height seems sufficient.

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo Yes. your original idea is on the right track.

Comment: Is there a similar method to prove ratio of volume of similar figures is equal to cube of ratio of corresponding sides?

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo I think a polyhedron can be divided into pyramids with the same point as vertices. The volume of the image pyramid  is (1/3)(base area)(height) = (1/3)(k.k. base area of the original)(k. height of the original) = (1/3)(k.k.k) (volume of the original pyramid).

Answer (score 1):

The function that scales the plane by a factor of $a$ can be written as $f((x,y))=(ax,ay)$. The Jacobian determinant of this function, which gives the area ratio of the transformed plane to the original, is
$$\begin{vmatrix}a&0\\0&a\end{vmatrix}=a^2$$
So scaling lengths by a factor of $a$ scales areas by a factor of $a^2$.